# Integrating $\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}$ and $\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}$

Tags: integration

How can I integrate the square rooted function? I’m having trouble regarding the substitution by a trigonometric ratio…

$$\sqrt{a^{2}+x^{2}}$$

And

$$\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}$$

Comment: There literally is a Wikipedia page for this. Why waste your ammo on MSE with this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution

Comment: That might have come out wrong, specially since you seem to be a new user. MSE is a tough crowd and there definitely is a social quota that gets drained as you ask questions (unless your question are ridiculously high quality), so I suggest you save your quota for stuff you can't easily find online.

Comment: Take $x=atan\theta$...

Comment: @GitGud - I don't think that's a fair comment. People are not familiar with trigonometric substitution, nor may they be familiar with how to best search for mathematical formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a^{2}+x^{2}$$
$$*Substituting x=atan\theta , we get:*$$
$$a^{2}+a^{2}tan^{2}\theta$$
$$=a^{2}(1+tan^{2}\theta)$$
$$=a^{2}sec^{2}\theta$$

In the square root , 
$$=asec\theta$$

Again , $$dx=asec^{2}\theta d\theta...$$
 So , the integral becomes :

$$∫a^{2}sec^{3}\theta$$
$$=∫a^{2}sec\theta(1+tan^{2}\theta)$$
$$=a^{2}∫sec\theta+a^{2}∫sec\theta.tan^{2}\theta$$
$$∫sec\theta=ln(sec\theta+tan\theta)$$
$$sec\theta.tan^{2}\theta=$$
$$=tan\theta.dsec\theta$$

Then apply substitution by parts...

The second integral can be solved by looking at the last part of the first one...

Comment: Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1):

Try using $x=a \sinh(u)$ as $a^2 + a^2 \sinh^2(u) = a^2 \cosh^2(u)$.

Try $x= a \sec(u)$ for the other. In each case you are exploiting a trig identity which you know (such as $\tan^2(u) + 1 = \sec^2(u)$) and multiplying through by $a$.

Comment: Thank you ... though I’m not aware of the function $cos h$...

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/trig/hyper/hyper01/hyper01.html This should explain them a little. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function